# Grouping and delete whole group with condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In pandas dataframe first I want to group the data with '`batch_id`' column then check in the '`result`' column if all values are negative delete that group

Using follwoing code

```
 df.groupby('batch_id').filter(lambda g: (g.result != 'negative').all())
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you have an example of things not working?

Comment: unique batch_id are 14405 after filtering I get only 20, which is not correct

Comment: about 2 million rows are reduced to just 367

Comment: Did you try   df.groupby('batch_id').filter(lambda g: ~ (g.result == 'negative').all())   on your data frame as I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create DF:

```
        df = pd.DataFrame({'batch_id':[5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3], \
          'result':['good','negative','2,000','negative', '66', \
           'negative','negative','negative', '22', 'clean']})

        batch_id    result
       0    5   good
       1    1   negative
       2    2   2,000
       3    3   negative
       4    4   66
       5    1   negative
       6    2   negative
       7    1   negative
       8    4   22
       9    3   clean

      df.groupby('batch_id').filter(lambda g: ~ (g.result == 'negative').all())
```

Output:

```
            batch_id    result
           0    5   good
           2    2   2,000
           3    3   negative
           4    4   66
           6    2   negative
           8    4   22
           9    3   clean
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, how I can do a small change that it will also filter those groups which only have one negative value. Delete group if  all values  are negative or  only 1 non negative

Comment: df.groupby('batch_id').filter(lambda g:  (~ ( (g.result == 'negative').all() ) & ~ (g.result == 'negative').sum() == 1) )      Can you try this.

Comment: h.groupby('batch_id').filter(lambda g:  ~ (( (g.result == 'negative').sum() > len(g) - 2 )) ) 
              Can you try this?

Comment: Did you try the new filter?       df.groupby('batch_id').filter(lambda g: ~ (( (g.result == 'negative').sum() > len(g) - 2 )) )

Comment: yes, I worked perfectly thank you very much for the help.